# Jetty WTP publishing to 2 directories which causes problem with GWT Development Mode

Tags: eclipse, gwt, jetty, eclipse-wtp

When publishing my web application to Jetty within Eclipse (WTP), the application is deployed to two different places!:

```
<eclipse-workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\TestApp
```

A temporary directory (here's an extract of the Jetty log):

> 2010-12-15 11:01:23.748:INFO::Deploy C:\jetty-6.1.26\contexts\TestApp.xml -> org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@1a12495{/TestApp,C:/jetty-6.1.26/webapps/TestApp.war}
>   2010-12-15 11:01:23.753:INFO::Extract C:/jetty-6.1.26/webapps/TestApp.war to C:\Users\Pete\AppData\Local\Temp\Jetty_127_0_0_1_8080_TestApp.war_*TestApp*_wi7r0g\webapp

First question - why would it publish to two places?

This is causing me a problem because when I run GWT's DevMode I need to give it the location of the war file. The only well-known location to me is the first directory (under the Eclipse workspace). The act of specifying this directory tells DevMode to create the module files there. The problem is this is not where Jetty serves the files from! I therefore get 404s on module.noncache.js, etc. when trying to test my application. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was using Jetty 6.1.26 which (at time of writing) is the latest one available from Mortbay/Codehaus. I was also using the Mortbay 1.0.4 WTP adaptor. I should've taken the Jetty distribution from Eclipse and used the Jetty WTP adaptor from Eclipse. *Thanks to Thomas Broyer on the GWT mailing list for pointing me in the right direction.*